# login Facebook registerCallback not called

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is my onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_login);
    init();
    hideActiveSocialNetworks();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // not called
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "callback success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // not called
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "callback cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            // not called
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "callback onError");
        }
    });

    final Activity activity = this;

    findViewById(R.id.fb_login_sdk).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "click");
            List<String> perm = new ArrayList<String>();
            perm.add("user_friends");
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, perm);
        }
    });
}
```

After login the onSuccess(), onCancel(), onError() methods are not fired.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

Comment: I had the exact same problem following the facebook docs.  Thanks for posting your question.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Missing this on my activity:

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: But how onActivityResult() is linked with LoginManager.registerCallback() ? just for knowledge anyone ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is checklist to check whether your Facebook Sdk setup is correct:-

1. Check your manifest if you have setup Facebook initialization properly.

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
       android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

   <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
       android:configChanges=
               "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
       android:label="@string/app_name" />
   <activity
       android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Create Facebook CallBackManager variable

   ```
   var fbCallManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
   ```
3. On Click of Login with Facebook button. Put your required permission in Array.

   ```
     LoginManager.getInstance()
       .logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"))
     LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(fbCallManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
       override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
          //login success
       }

       override fun onCancel() {
           //login cancelled by user

       }

       override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
           //login error handle exception
       }

   })
   ```

   }
4. Add callback result in onActivityResult method

   ```
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       fbCallManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
   }
   ```
5. Provide the Development and Release Key Hashes for Your

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME.android\debug.keystore" | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64

> [Download openssl from here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads?fbclid=IwAR1A8cdroVdzLuNY0dSAUsiUsAhkZLifgZMDNraflYPSk5_P8NuU7O6Tzu0)

6. Setup your Keyhash and Launcher activity in Facebook developer console.

References : [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

Answer (score 0):

**Your code will work when you add this to your activity class**

```
 @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```