# Pressing Facebook Login button does nothing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Here is how I implemented callback mechanism for FB login button:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                Log.d("FB onSuccess 1", "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("FB onCancel 1", "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d("FB onError 1", "");
            }
        });
    }
```

When pressing button a spinner appear, starts, but the confirmation screen does not appear, and no log messages are filled into Activity Monitor. What is the problem?

Comment: Try to add this line  `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));`

Comment: have look on this may be it help you https://github.com/sushildlh/AllProjetcs/blob/master/TestforFacebook/app/src/main/java/com/car/ensieg/testforfacebook/MainActivity.java

Comment: @bigdestroyer set permission helped, FB screen appeared, but still `onSuccess` case is not called. Do you know why not?

Comment: @János Maybe this helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599301/login-facebook-registercallback-not-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding this in your Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: Now after pressing button, title change to `Log out`, but still the `onSuccess` or any other methods in callback is not get called. Do you know why?

Comment: On Your button click add this code  `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));`